# CORINE LandCover: what about the accuracy?

Tags: accuracy, land-cover

How accurate is CLC? Do anyone know any scientific papers about that question? I tested the new CLC2006 for a region in turkey and its totally rubbish!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does vary by Country - Turkey is poor because the data they used is minimal.
For France, Germany, UK, Ireland the data accuracy is vastly better.

If you want the accepted paper on the project

"The Corine Land Cover (CLC2000) database received a thumbs up for accuracy from an assessment of the project, details of which were released by the EEA today.

CLC2000 uses photo-interpretation of satellite images to show the impact of human activities on land use over a ten year period between **1990 and 2000**. The spread of housing, food production and transport networks are all illustrated by the system. It also shows land cover changes in ecosystems, such as forests and lakes.

The accuracy of the CLC2000 'images' were validated by comparing them to other imaging types, such as ground based photography and written observations.**The exercise shows that the database exceeded the 85% accuracy requirement set down in its technical guidelines**."

**"The thematic accuracy of Corine land cover 2000 - Assessment using LUCAS"**
is available here:

http://www.eea.europa.eu/publications/technical_report_2006_7 [5.8mb PDF]

Published by

```
EEA (European Environment Agency)
OPOCE (Office for Official Publications of the European Communities)
Published: Jun 27, 2006
```

source:
http://www.eea.europa.eu/highlights/Ann1151398593